# If a table gets mobile size, move rows

Tags: html, html-table, rows, responsive

I've trouble getting a table responsive.

What iIhave:

```html
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td style="width:25%">Selection </td>
     <!-- breakline if res below 643px -->
     <td style="width:15%">Other, like: </td>
     <td style="width:60%">insert text field</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need to know how to get that breakline when the resolution gets below 643px.

Answer (score 0):

You could set all the td of the table to 100% and float:left, so that they will move one under another.
Also for changes to work add to your CSS style a media query like:

```
@media (max-width: 643px){
 /* your changes */
}
```

Comment: That did not solve the problem, If I set them all to 100 % it still stays in 1 row resulting in the first row getting about 80 % and the other 2 about 10 % each... thanks anyway